# How can I get the main duplicated video Id

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I developed the application to upload the video to youtube with Youtube API, I know that youtube doesn't accept to upload the same video more than once. So Im checking the Video Status and check whether its processed successfully or not. But if the status is Rejected and Reason code equal duplicated, I want to get the main video id, is there any way to get the source duplicated video Id?

(I know I can get the list of all uploaded video and compare with some properties, but I'm looking for Google API)

Answer (score 1):

When a video is marked as a duplicate, there's no way to retrieve the id of the "original" video as part of the API response. This is a fairly common feature request, but implementing it is something that the engineering team has decided is not feasible.

Comment: Hello in api v3 youtube it's always actually ?